# Plotly: Make a plot that doesn't change proportions when zoomed in

Tags: python, plot, plotly, drawing, graph-theory

I'm making a custom plot using Plotly for representing a [condensed complete directed graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4693604/succinct-represention-of-a-condensed-complete-directed-graph). I've worked hard to get the shapes right and it's still a work-in-progress. However, I noticed a problem: The scale between pixel and data coordinated isn't fixed.

For example, here is a screenshot of such a plot that my code made (excuse the ugliness):

[image]

Here's the same plot, but zoomed into the area of the "0" node:

[image]

The shapes are out of proportion. This is because Plotly seems to have two different worlds of coordinates:

1. Pixels, which are used for width of lines, sizes of fonts and sizes of markers, and
2. Data coordinates, which are used for placing scatter points on the figure.

Because zooming in or out only pertains to the data coordinates and not the pixels, the picture changes when you zoom in and out.

**I want to design my plot so it doesn't change any of its proportions when you zoom in or out. Is that possible with Plotly? If not, what other tool would you recommended?**

(Note: I know that the `fixedrange` argument exists, but I would not like to disable zoom, just make it zoom everything equally.)

Answer (score 0):

I came to the conclusion that Plotly isn't the right tool for the job, and I'm now working on using `svgwrite` to just write an SVG file.